# resizing div through javascript on overflow scroll resets position to left

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

as part of a bigger system I have divs which are draggable by a user which increase it's width from javascript.

The wrapper div has overflow: auto;

for a scroll as there can be many divs which the user can adjust the width. However, if the scroll is moved let's say on the last div on the right and the width of a div is increased or decreased, instead of staying where we are the scroll will always push to the left (this only happens when increasing the width).

Is there a CSS solution to stop this happening?

Thanks

---

As it's part of a bigger system it's hard to post the javascript for it, the styling for the resizable divs is:

```
overflow: auto;
text-align: left;
position: relative;
```

To make the question more general I've created a basic fiddle with anchors. If you scroll to the bottom and click on the 'test 2' anchor it will go to the top. This is doing the same kind of thing, so I would like the scroll to stay at the bottom. The fiddle link is:

https://jsfiddle.net/x6tfaky4/

Thank you

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Please provide `fiddle` till now whatever you tried.

Comment: I've made a fiddle with a general showing of the issue. Please see my edit.

Comment: @frontender using `javascript` or `jquery` is possible that your scroll will remain at last, whether element width increases or decrease.

Answer (score 0):

Against your fiddle, here is what you can do to prevent the page from going to top:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">test2</a>
```

Instead of `#` put `javascript:void(0)` in the `href` attribute to prevent your page from navigating to top.